# Where to learn Temperature Dependent Conductivity induced by Electron-Phonon Interaction?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons

I want to learn how to calculate the temperature dependent conductivity induced by electron-phonon interaction.

I know in low temperature, the resistance in metal $\rho$ is proportional to $T^5$, $T$ is the temperature. In high temperature region, $\rho$ is linear to $T$.

Could someone tell me which text book and which chapter can I find related calculations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This the classic:

http://www.amazon.com/Electrons-Phonons-Transport-Phenomena-Physical/dp/0198507798

You can also find chapter 2 of:

http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Carrier-Transport-Mark-Lundstrom/dp/0521637244

to be pretty concise and self-contained.

Comment: [Many Particle physics](http://www.amazon.com/Many-Particle-Physics-Solids-Liquids/dp/1441933395) by Mahan